# SSIS 2014 issue with currency (Without Decimal) in a flat file source

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am importing data from a flat file to Sql server database. In a flat file data comes without decimal like 3000 for 30.00. I tried setting up this column to DT_Decimal with DataScale 2 or DT_Numeric with precision (12 - 18) and DataScle 2 and I also tried DT_CY Currency. All these are inserting value as 3000.00 in database instead of 30.00. I don't know how to implement this?

Comment: How would it know to turn the 3000 into 30.00? Giving it a precision and scale will not change the value.

Comment: How can I insert 30 in db for 3000 from a flat file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it with the following steps:

1) Created and opened, an SSIS project

2) Added a dataflow task

3) Created a flat file source

4) Created two step transform:

```
4a) Data Transformation to a dt_decimal

4b) Derived Column with the Expression: decColumn0 / 100
```

5) Ole DbDestination

Comment: Thanks I followed the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the decimal. Use a staging table to import the raw data, then select out of it using something like the below into your production table.

```
declare @textval varchar(18) = '3000'

select CONVERT(Decimal(18,2),Left(@Textval, LEN(@Textval)-2) + '.' + Right(@Textval,2))
```